# How to get Pycrypto to use my random number and not its own when creating an RSA key?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, raspberry-pi, encryption-asymmetric

In PyCrypto I want to create an RSA key using the hardware random number generator on the raspberry pi. I already have access to the data from the Pis hrng but I do not know how to use/give that data to the PyCrypto function that creates the RSA key, `RSA.generate()`.

The [documentation](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA-module.html) from PyCrypto on the generate function seems to indicate that I need to pass a function that will return a random number and not the random number itself. Does anyone know how I can use my captured hardware random numbers to create an RSA key within python and more specificly using PyCrypto. Below is some sample code of what I have toyed with.

This generated an RSA key but does not use truly random numbers to do so:

```
#/usr/bin/python

from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random

random_generator = Random.new().read
key = RSA.generate(1024, random_generator)
print 'Random_generate', random_generator
print 'key: ', key
```

This is kind of what I want but the `randomStream` variable in the `generate()` is incorrect usage of the generate function.

```
#/usr/bin/python

from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random

hwrngFile = open('/dev/hwrng', 'r')
randomStream = hwrngFile.read(512)
hwrngFile.close()

key = RSA.generate(4096, randomStream)
print key
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass in `hwrngFile.read`. Don't close `hwrngFile` before generating the key.

The documentation says:

> randfunc (callable) - Random number generation function; it should
>   accept a single integer N and return a string of random data N bytes
>   long.

So, `hwrngFile.read` is a function, it accepts an integer, it returns that number of bytes. Great.

Your code should look like:

```
with open('/dev/hwrng', 'r') as hwrgnFile:
    key = RSA.generate(4096, hwrngFile.read)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with python, but in many other languages the reading from a file/stream may return fewer bytes than requested even if you didn't reach the end of the file yet.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Python isn't one of them. `open` returns a buffered IO object. Except on ttys, it reads until the requested size is reached, or error or EOF. On ttys a buffered IO can return short without reaching EOF, so I've assumed without proof that the Raspberry Pi doesn't mark its RNG as interactive.

Comment: what should be content of this file? I tried putting integers into it but it seems it is not accepting. Please suggest.

Comment: @Gauranga: `/dev/hwrng` is not a normal file, it's the HardWare Random Number Generator device. If it's not present on your system then you're out of luck, but you could look for other random devices that are available on your system (such as `/dev/urandom`).